# show custom annotation in mapkit

Tags: ios, swift3, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapitem

I'm trying to show an image annotation instead of a pin annotation on the mapkit. I'm using this code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController , MKMapViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.889281, 75.836042)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)



        var info1 = CustomPointAnnotation()
        info1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.889281, 75.836042)
        info1.title = "Info1"
        info1.subtitle = "Subtitle"
        info1.imageName = "taxi"

        var info2 = CustomPointAnnotation()
        info2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.862280, 75.815098)
        info2.title = "Info2"
        info2.subtitle = "Subtitle"
        info2.imageName = "smile"

        mapView.addAnnotation(info1)
        mapView.addAnnotation(info2)

        mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        print("delegate called")

        if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "test"

        var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if anView == nil {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView?.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else {
            anView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
        //the view is dequeued or created...

        let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
        anView?.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

        return anView
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }


}

class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String!
}
```

I think this method is not calling `viewForAnnotation`, although I connect the delegate with `viewcontroller : mapView.delegate = self`.

I still see the pin annotation instead of `custominnotation` on the map:

[image: Map]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift MapKit Custom Annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274115/ios-swift-mapkit-custom-annotation)

Comment: If you are familiar with setting break points and tracing your code, see when the code comes to your viewForAnnotation delegate does it pass the "if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation)" or it return's there.

Answer (score 0):

**Now when implement this code:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController , MKMapViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mapView.delegate = self
        
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.889281, 75.836042)
        
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)    
        
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Annotation Created"
        annotation.subtitle = "mahdi"
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.889281, 75.836042)
        
        let annotation2 = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation2.title = "Annotation Created"
        annotation2.subtitle = "mahdi"
        annotation2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.862280, 75.815098)            
        
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation2)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        
        guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"
        
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
            annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }
        
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "taxi")
        
        return annotationView
        
    }
```

**I can see the two images annotations like this:**

[image: Screenshot]

now i want to include this image with user location , i try with this code but still see the red pin annotation instead of image

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        
        if let location = manager.location?.coordinate {
            
            userLocation  = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
            
           // print(userLocation)
            
            if driverOnTheWay == false {
                
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
                self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)
                
                
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.title = "مكانك هنا"
                annotation.subtitle = "mahdi"
                annotation.coordinate = userLocation
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                
                
                
                
            }
            
            func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
                
                guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else {
                    
                    return nil
                }
                
                let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"
                
                var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
                
                if annotationView == nil {
                    annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
                    annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
                    annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
                }
                else {
                    annotationView!.annotation = annotation
                }
                
                annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "car")
                
                return annotationView
                
            }
```

how can show car image with user location