# Apple maps show customies pin details and alway open mode

Tags: swift, apple-maps

I am working on Apple maps and I have two tasks to perform

- Show customized pin icon and customized pin detail view always open
- Click on Pin detail action.

[image: Map Image]

I have followed some tutorials but failed to complete the above mentioned tasks.

Comment: please share more for better explanation

Comment: @emrcftci actually, he can find many Q&A in SO like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/38274115/4711785

Comment: @emrcftci Simple Apple map with custom Pin, Pin Detail View and on Click on Detail view Custom Action.

Comment: @emrcftci Thanks Buddy